# azure devops self-managed agent installation on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntlm, azure-devops, azure-cli

my environment is Ubuntu 20.04, after running ./config.cmd command and adding my correct details
I get the following error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: NTLM authentication is not possible with default credentials on this platform.
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(String package, Boolean isServer, NetworkCredential credential)
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.Initialize(Boolean isServer, String package, NetworkCredential credential, String spn, ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithNtAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean isProxyAuth, HttpConnection connection, HttpConnectionPool connectionPool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnel(HttpRequestHeaders headers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.LocationServer.ConnectAsync(VssConnection jobConnection)
```

Comment: That is because NTLM authentication is not possible with default credentials on your platform. This may be because of [Bug 28961](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28961).

Comment: my platform does supports NTLM authentication, It was an enterprise proxy issue
I used curl to test the endpoints described in self-managed agents behind proxy configuration documentation and made sure it is a proxy bypass not configured issue, because the response http status code was 407 "Proxy Authentication Required" + 401 "Unauthorized"

Comment: After Proxy bypass was configured I tried again with curl -I https://dev.azure.com -v and the response was 301 "redirected" which means that I can connect to the domain "https://dev.azure.com by default redirects you to a login page"